# problems with debugging vb.net application after plattform change

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, debugging, 32bit-64bit

I have an vb.net application build in ViusalStudio2010. I am using an oracle database and after a change of the oracle.dataaccess client from a 32bit client to a 64bit client and changing the corresponding vb.net-platform values i have problems to debug the application. When I build the application, i can start the builded .exe-file without problems. But debugging via VisualStudio does not work, I get the following error message:

> Error executing the project: The file or assembly "MyProjectName" or one of its dependencies not found. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

The aim-CPU in Visual Studio is on x64, the compiling plattform too, as you can see in the following pictures.

Here are the compiling values:
[image: compiling values]

[image: more compiling properties, including aim-cpu]

And here the one for debugging:
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you referencing the 64-bit client?

Comment: Yes, i reference it

Comment: You have to install the 64 bit Oracle Client. Follow this instruction to install both 32 bit and 64 bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: To run in VS, which is 32-bit, I think you need to target `AnyCPU`. Thus, it should do 32-bit in debug mode and 64-bit in compiled mode.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the solution & then rebuild it again!

Comment: may be you are missing some of your files from solution. are you migrating your project to upper version of .net framework?

Comment: I have deleted all bin and obj folders, but no change.

Comment: ran into this many times. Typically because the server has a different version than my PC. I normally code my stuff in one version then change the version when I deploy to the server. More of a work around.